# Linear Space of real square matrices whose sum of first minors is 0

Tags: matrices

I am considering the following subset of nonsingular matrices $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$: $X = \{A \in GL_n(\mathbb{R}): \sum_{i,j} A_{ij} = 0\}$ where $A_{ij}$ is the first minor of $A$, corresponding to $i,j$. This means $A_{ij}$ equals to $(-1)^{i+j}$, multiplied with the determinant of submatrix of $A$ by deleting row i, column j. X is not a linear space, it is easy to see it. But I wonder if there is a 2-dimensional linear subspace of X? This question arises when I consider entry pattern matrices.

Comment: As $0\notin GL_(\Bbb R)$, there is no vector subspace whatsoever. Do you mean affine space?

Comment: thanks for the comments. Actually, I mean a subspace of $X \cup \{0\}$.

Comment: X is also the set of nonsingular matrices A such that $1^T \cdot A^{-1} \cdot 1 = 0$ where 1 is the column vector whose entries are full of 1.